# <style> tag in HTML file not showing up in browser

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning html and css.
While reading a tutorial from a book I saw how to change the styles
I wrote the same code but there is no effect on the page in the browser.
It appears just the same as without the `<style>` tag.

Here's the code:

```
<title> Starbuzz Coffee </title>  
<style type=”text/css”>
    body {

        background-color: #d2b48c;  
        margin-left: 20%;  
        margin-right: 20%;
        border: 1px dotted gray;  
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;    
        font-family: sans-serif;  
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Youy quotes `""` might be problem. i guess!

Comment: Change your quotations

Comment: I don't see a problem in above. - http://jsfiddle.net/029udnpk/

Comment: Did you add the `<body>` tag somewhere in your code ?

Comment: We need to see more, like the html of the page, specifically the `body` tag

Comment: Yes, I have added the body tag. It's where I show the menu

Comment: Yes, it was the quotation marks where I went wrong. Thanks a lot. Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: stop copy pasting code from online website and write yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `<style type=”text/css”>` to `<style type="text/css">`.

The key problem here is with your quote. I've just tested using `”` which didn't work in my local project.

Comment: Thanks a ton, you are right. I was wrong with the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks are the issue, you need to use `"` instead of `”`

Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Also, lets go to the next level too. Adding styles in the HTML head is ok, but you will find it a lot easier to maintain your HTML and CSS code in the future if you link to a separate stylesheet. To do that, just add the following to your HTML head:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

In this case your stylesheet is called 'mystyle.css' and is located in the same folder as your HTML page...
You can now add all of your CSS goodness into the 'mystyle.css' file like this:

```
body {
  background-color: #d2b48c;  
  margin-left: 20%;  
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;  
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;    
  font-family: sans-serif;  
}
```

Read more about this [on W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the info, quite helpful

Answer (score -2):

You can try couple of thing to test

1. Open a debugger window by pressing F12 and find body tag to see what has overwritten it.
2. Try inline style on a body tag and see does that make a difference
3. Change the order of a CSS on your page.